# Is there a way to move guides with a layer in gimp?

Tags: gimp

While creating tile sets or  similar sprites I end up having multiple guides as measurements in a layer. Is there a way to collectively move a group of guides with the layer when I am arranging and organizing it in my canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, because the guides are actually connected to the canvas.

If you create guides from the layer sides (to abut them, etc...), you can recreate them :

- if the layer is a "tight crop": `Layers > Transparency > Alpha to selection` and `Image > Guides > Guides from selection`
- in the general cases, there are also scripts that will do this

And if this is to abut layers, there are also scripts for this.

Comment: Thanks for the input.